# [visual-studio-2008] and [visual-studio-2010] should not be synonyms of [visual-studio]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

It has been suggested that [visual-studio-2008] and [visual-studio-2010] should be synonyms of [visual-studio].  I disagree.  There are issues specific to each version of Visual Studio just as there are issues specific to each version of any piece of software.

Visit the [visual-studio tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=info&tagnames=visual-studio) and cast your vote.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend only bringing this stuff to meta if it **has** become a vetted synonym. Otherwise we will have 100s of requests like this.

Also we need to clarify on that page the synonyms means interchangeable **NOT** similar.

Comment: I guess I don't understand this synonym system yet.  I don't know what it means for a synonym to be "vetted".  I saw it on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms and assumed it was already locked in.  I'll sit back and watch for a while longer.

Comment: @raven, you can filter by "active" which are active synonyms or "suggested", ones that are still in the voting phase.